# Run Javascript code on webbrowser website

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webbrowser-control

What I have is simple, a form with in that form a webbrowser-controll.

That webbrowser goes to a website. And that all works.

But what I wan't to do when he's on the page is to let him run some javascript code (or jQuery if that's possible) to get all the text thats between the `<b></b>` tags on the website.

How should I do that?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Birk, the code now looks like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection bigFontTags = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Frame_A").Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");
            string[] textPieces = new string[bigFontTags.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < bigFontTags.Count; i++) {
                textPieces[i] = bigFontTags[i].InnerText;
            }
            //process text
            string bigText = String.Join(" ", textPieces);
            MessageBox.Show(bigText);
```

But that doesn't work. That is because the element that i need to get, is deep inside frame's and frameset's.... This is the layout (simple):

```
<frameset rows="0,1000" border="0" frameborder="0">

    <frame src="/mail/Login?domain=telfort.nl&amp;style=default&amp;plain=0" name="SContentFrame" id="SContentFrame" scrolling="Auto" noresize="">
    <frameset rows="88,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">

        <frameset cols="182,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" onunload="ExitLogout()" onload="LoadFrames('/mail/Navigation?sid=1FBE4F29181F18D9358ABC082C7DEE1B6C67481B&amp;userid=marcmeesters%40telfort.nl&amp;seq=+Q&amp;auth=+A&amp;style=default','/mail/MessageList?sid=1FBE4F29181F18D9358ABC082C7DEE1B6C67481B&amp;userid=marcmeesters%40telfort.nl&amp;seq=+Q&amp;auth=+A&amp;srcfolder=INBOX&amp;chk=1&amp;style=default')">

        <frame src="/supp/blank.htm" name="Frame_A" id="Frame_A" frameborder="0" scrolling="Yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" border="0">
        <form name="phoenix" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return clickedButton">
And then are here some tables and the content that i want to get.....
```

So how can i get that content from there??? (in a nice way???)

**EDIT2:**
I will post the generated source of the website: (NOTE! i've deleted everything that wassn't relevant... So only the way from the begin to the content)

```
<html><head>
<title>Telfort - Webmail</title>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.telfort.nl/images/template/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/telfort/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<!-- main.tpl 20001107 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/supp/phsec.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/supp/client_sniffer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension://bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn/js/injected.js"></script></head>
<frameset rows="0,1000" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame src="/mail/Login?domain=telfort.nl&amp;style=default&amp;plain=0" name="SContentFrame" id="SContentFrame" scrolling="Auto" noresize="">
        <html><head>
        <title>Telfort - Webmail</title>
        <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.telfort.nl/images/template/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/telfort/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <!-- main.tpl 20001107 -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/supp/phsec.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/supp/client_sniffer.js"></script>
        </head>
        <frameset rows="0,1000" border="0" frameborder="0">
            <frame src="/mail/Login?domain=telfort.nl&amp;style=default&amp;plain=0" name="SContentFrame" id="SContentFrame" scrolling="Auto" noresize="">
                <html><head>
                <title>Telfort - Webmail</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/telfort/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
                <!-- main_frame.tpl 20060510 -->
                <script src="/supp/phif.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--
                function LoadFrames(t1,t2) {
                  NavWin(frames["Frame_NAV"],t1);
                  NavWin(frames["Frame_A"],t2);
                }

                function ExitLogout() {
                  window.open(NavURL("/mail/Logout?sid=5D3995C305E2F91F575EDF1E2F11F5D75A7DF6D8&userid=marcmeesters%40telfort.nl&seq=+Q&auth=+A&style=default&popup=1"),"Logout","resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=0,width=10,height=10");
                }
                //-->
                </script>
                </head>
                <frameset rows="88,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <frameset cols="182,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" onunload="ExitLogout()" onload="LoadFrames('/mail/Navigation?sid=5D3995C305E2F91F575EDF1E2F11F5D75A7DF6D8&amp;userid=marcmeesters%40telfort.nl&amp;seq=+Q&amp;auth=+A&amp;style=default','/mail/MessageList?sid=5D3995C305E2F91F575EDF1E2F11F5D75A7DF6D8&amp;userid=marcmeesters%40telfort.nl&amp;seq=+Q&amp;auth=+A&amp;srcfolder=INBOX&amp;chk=1&amp;style=default')">
                        <frame src="/supp/blank.htm" name="Frame_A" id="Frame_A" frameborder="0" scrolling="Yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" border="0">
                            <html><head>
                            <title>Berichtenlijst</title>
                            <!-- folders_msglist.tpl 20001106 -->

                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/telfort/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
                            </head>
                            <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
                            <form name="phoenix" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return clickedButton">

                            AND HERE THE CONTENT!!!!
                            </form>
                    </frameset>
                </frameset>
        </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3 :**
Thanks to Birk, the problem is solved, and this is the answer:

```
HtmlWindow SContentFrame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[1];
            HtmlWindow Frame_A = SContentFrame.Document.Window.Frames[2];
            HtmlElementCollection bigFontTags = Frame_A.Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");
            string[] textPieces = new string[bigFontTags.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < bigFontTags.Count; i++) {
            textPieces[i] = bigFontTags[i].InnerText;
            }
            string bigText = String.Join(" ", textPieces);
            MessageBox.Show(bigText);
```

Comment: `eval()`?  (* *Lix ducks and dives* *)

Comment: alright, but how does i run that in the C# program???

Comment: Your final output (if this is for a browser) should be HTML content.  Within that HTML content you can embed some JavaScript utilities.  I have no knowledge of `C#` so I can't really help you with any syntax... sorry...

Comment: alright, thank you annyway with the javascript part ;-)

Comment: Add some words to clarify you're using winform and the WebBrowser control

Comment: i'm using visual C# 2010, and simply dragged the webbrowser into the form, so that's why i use it. I've got no reason (yet) to do it not that way.....

And what i trying to make is a extender of a webpage. So if there are new message's on that page (those are in the bold tags) than output it in the label with the name dynamic_new_message...

But before i can do that, i need to get the text of the page, and that's where i'm stuck....

Comment: Sounds like you want to get at the content in the browser from the outside form.  To do this you don't need javascript.  There is a DocumentText property on the WebBrowser you can do string searches on.  There's a Document property if you want to search the DOM.

Comment: THere's only one problem, the new content and the old content doesn't have id's or classes that seperates them only the image is diffrent.

But how would you let him take the content of the website (what's between the <b> tag</b> into an array with a new entry for every new b tag???

Comment: Probably something like webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("B").Cast<HtmlElement>().Select(e => e.InnerHtml).ToArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DocumentCompleted-event and process all tags using `((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");`.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection bigFontTags = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");
            string[] textPieces=new string[bigFontTags.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < bigFontTags.Count; i++)
            {
                textPieces[i] = bigFontTags[i].InnerText;
            }
            //process text
            string bigText = String.Join(" ", textPieces);
            MessageBox.Show(bigText);
        }
```

That's not JavaScript, but the result is exactly the same.

EDIT #2: For all those nested frames you could use:

```
HtmlElementCollection bigFontTags = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SContentFrame").Document.GetElementById("SContentFrame").Document.GetElementById("Frame_A").Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");
```

That should work, if I understand your frameset structure correctly.

Comment: alright, but how does i call that method??? Because i wan't to get the text when i press an button... i got the button click event already...

Comment: Simply replace `((WebBrowser)sender)` by `webBrowser1` (or the name of your webbrowser).

Comment: damm, if i wish i new that first :D Now no errors, but there's only one problem, the content that i wan't to get is in a iframe.

The id of that frame is (Frame_A). so can i do something like Document.GetElemntById("Frame_A").Document.GetElementsByTagNme("b")  or do you know a better way???

Comment: No, I guess, that would be the best way to do it.
`webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Frame_A").Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");`

Comment: That didn't work, that's because the frame goes realy deep. I updated the question, so you can understand it how deep it is ;)

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your frameset-construction.

Comment: alright, when i run the program, i get this error:

The value of 2 is not valid for index. index must lie between 0 and 0.
Parameter name: index

Am i something missing???

Comment: Can you post all your framesets? I cannot see which frame is in which one. Is each frameset you show in your question in a separate page?

Comment: eeuuhm, i'm feeling myself really dump right now... The error that i get now is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: No, the problem is the frame structure, but I cannot find the error.

Your structure: `Element-ID: SContentFrame`>`Element-ID: SContentFrame`>`Element-ID: Frame_A`, that structure is exactly retreived by my code, but I don't know any reason for the error.

Comment: mayby because it's in a frameset????

And when i only use this line (just for testing):HtmlElementCollection bigFontTags = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SContentFrame");

I get this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection'

Mayby that helps???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13910/discussion-between-birk-and-twcrap)